# Is Bootstrap capable of producing this layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to code a layout (http://lancebitner.com/Story%20580_WAGE_Yes.pdf) using Bootstrap and I am not sure if it is possible.  I have limited experience with Bootstrap, but more experience with HTML and CSS. I am not sure it is possible as I have not been able to find any references for this layout. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Each page has different features and I am hoping to produce them each with Bootstrap.

Has anyone seen a site similar to this mockup, with the layout and features, that uses Bootstrap?

Comment: probably not exactly . bootstrap is actually a collection of markup and css rules that will make it look different ( but a lot better )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and you guys were right, Bootstrap can do it; it just takes some custom CSS and JS. I found a Bootstrap layout with some of the features I was looking for; single column layout with a drop down menu: http://alijafarian.com/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/ .  Also, for the two column page I found this layout: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/2-col-portfolio/ .  These to layout will help tremendously. With some adjustments I am on my way!

http://lancebitner.com/Capture2.PNG

Answer (score 6):

Any design can be done using bootstrap, its about how are you going to manipulate or edit the existing code, but for me the best part of bootstrap is the grid system, which will allow you to have a better responsive design.

Answer (score 4):

probably not exactly . bootstrap is actually a grid system with a collection of markup and css rules that will make it look different a bit ( but a lot better ).
That means that some elements will look different ( buttons, form elements etc ) if you will use the default rules - But you can always override them .. but then again - why use bootstrap :-)

as a direct answer - For layout by itself ( ignoring the design ) - yes, you can.

bootstrap will also give you the advantage of device / browser compatibility that is hard to achieve coding from 0 in HTML these days .

I suggest you go to the [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) page where you can see some layouts to start from - combining these will allow you to achieve the layout you need . Also pass all the elements and [components](https://getbootstrap.com/components/) ( [form](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), [table](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables), [buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) etc) that are showcased on the official page. all the elements you need are there ( and more )

In order to understand bootstrap the best way iss just to implement it .

Comment: Without any custom CSS it would be impossible. Using Bootstrap in addition to custom CSS, of course.

Comment: - Meant to reply to OP

Comment: Our client wants to use Bootstrap and I wanted to know if it was possible. I don't want to override the Bootstrap CSS since it will be used on other sites. I just wanted to use their classes and IDs on the features on the mockup.

Answer (score 2):

Good day,

Yes, it's possible and judging with the pdf, you can use some free bootstrap templates here, just tweak it

https://bootswatch.com/, 
http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/

Cheers :)